# How to organize Swift View controller classes with the Xibs in a project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

this is a question regarding conventions in XCode project structures. I've seen many project structures in my ~2 years as an iOS Developer (Mostly MVVM and MVC). However, one thing that confuses me is where in the project should I put my `XIB` files and their corresponding Controller files. So 2 I have seen more popularly are:

1. Inside the Views group

```
|- Models
|- Views
    |- Reusables
       |- NameOfView
          |- View.xib   <-- xib file
          |- View.swift <-- Controller class
| - Controllers
```

2. Xib inside Views and controller inside Controller

```
|- Models
|- Views
    |- Reusables
       |- NameOfView
          |- View.xib   <-- xib file
| - Controllers
    |- ViewcontrollerA.swift
    |- Reusables
       |- NameOfView
          |- View.swift <-- Controller class
```

My question is, which one is the better structure to follow? Personally, I feel like the 1st makes more sense because the `Xib` and `Swift` are in close proximity making it easier to find the necessary files. But do give me your opinions, or even other structures I could possibly follow for personal projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
|- Services/Utilities
    |- RestServices
    |- LocalizationUtil
|- Resources
    |- Colors
    |- Images
    |- Fonts
|- Models
|- BaseViews/Views/ReusableViews
    |- Views that are reusable for different scenes 
|- Scenes
    |- Splash
        |- SplashViewController.swift
        |- SplashViewController.xib
    |- Home
        |- Views
            |- TitleView.swift
            |- TitleView.xib
        |- Cells
            |- ExampleHomeTableViewCell.swift
            |- ExampleHomeTableViewCell.xib
        |- HomeViewController.swift
        |- HomeViewController.xib
        |- HomeViewModel.swift
        |- HomeViewModelProtocol.swift
```